# Efficient to way to check if user_id is present in User and either match or queue?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy 2.0. I have  3 table User, Match, Queue.

```
class User(Base, TableNameMixin):
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    premium: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default=text("false"))
    bonus_count: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(SmallInteger, server_default=text("0"))
    age: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(SmallInteger, nullable=True)
    min_age: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(SmallInteger, nullable=True)
    max_age: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(SmallInteger, nullable=True)
    language: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(3), server_default=text("'en'"))
    preferred_language: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(3), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.user_id}>"
```

```
class Match(Base, TableNameMixin):
    match_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user1_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
    user2_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
    is_matched: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default=text("false"))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="matchs")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Match {self.match_id}>"
```

```
class Queue(Base, TableNameMixin):
   queue_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BIGINT, nullable=False)
   in_queue: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default=text("true"))

   user = relationship("User", back_populates="queues")

   def __repr__(self):
       return f"<Queue {self.queue_id}>"
```

What will be efficient to way to check if user_id is present in User and either match or queue.How to query in which table user id is present How to make sure it doesn't overlap?